# D3 Tree Chart with D3 Donut Chart Node

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js, charts

I want to add Donut chart in each node of D3 tree chart (replace circle node in tree with Donut Chart)

Below is my Code. I want to replace the circle node with Donut chart in each node with different data that sholud be read from sample json.

```js
// Sample JSON Data 
var jsondata = {
  "name": "CERT",
  "children": [{
    "name": ""
  }, {
    "name": ""
  }, {
    "name": "DNS",
    "children": [{
      "name": "FW",
      "children": [{
        "name": ""
      }, {
        "name": ""
      }, {
        "name": "ADC",
        "children": [{
          "name": ""
        }, {
          "name": ""
        }, {
          "name": "SERVERS",
          "children": [{
            "name": ""
          }, {
            "name": ""
          }]
        }]
      }]
    }]
  }, {
    "name": "FW",
    "children": [{
      "name": ""
    }, {
      "name": ""
    }, {
      "name": "DNS",
      "children": [{
        "name": ""
      }, {
        "name": ""
      }, {
        "name": "ADC",
        "children": [{
          "name": "SERVERS"
        }]
      }]
    }]
  }]
};

var margin = {
    top: 20,
    right: 120,
    bottom: 20,
    left: 120
  },
  //width = 960 - margin.right - margin.left, height = 800 - margin.top - margin.bottom;
  width = screen.width;
height = 800 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var i = 0,
  duration = 750,
  root;

var tree = d3.layout.tree()
  .separation(function(a, b) {
    return a.parent === b.parent ? 1 : 2;
  })
  .children(function(d) {
    return d.children;
  })
  .size([height, width]);


var diagonal = d3.svg.diagonal()
  .projection(function(d) {
    return [d.y, d.x];
  });

var line = d3.svg.line()
  .x(function(d) {
    return d.x;
  })
  .y(function(d) {
    return d.y;
  });

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
  .attr("width", width + margin.right + margin.left)
  .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")")
  .call(zm = d3.behavior.zoom().scaleExtent([1, 13]).on("zoom", redraw)).append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + 350 + "," + 20 + ")");;

// put JSON data to root variable 
root = jsondata;
root.x0 = height / 2;
root.y0 = 0;

//necessary so that zoom knows where to zoom and unzoom from
zm.translate([350, 20]);
update(root);

//d3.select(self.frameElement).style("height", "800px");

function update(source) {


  // Compute the new tree layout.
  var nodes = tree.nodes(root).reverse(),
    links = tree.links(nodes);

  // Normalize for fixed-depth.
  nodes.forEach(function(d) {
    d.y = d.depth * 180;
  });


  // Update the nodes 
  var node = svg.selectAll("g.node")
    .data(nodes, function(d) {
      return d.id || (d.id = ++i);
    });

  // Enter any new nodes at the parent's previous position.
  var nodeEnter = node.enter().append("g")
    .attr("class", "node")
    .attr("transform", function(d) {
      return "translate(" + source.y0 + "," + source.x0 + ")";
    })
    .on("click", click)
    .on("mouseover", function(d) {
      var g = d3.select(this); // The node
      // The class is used to remove the additional text later
      var info = g.append('text')
        .classed('info', true)
        .attr('x', 30)
        .attr('y', 10)
        .text(function(d) {
          return d.name;
        });
    })
    // Remove the info text on mouse out.
    .on("mouseout", function() {
      d3.select(this).select('text.info').remove();
    });

  nodeEnter.append("circle")
    .attr("r", 1e-6)
    .style("fill", function(d) {
      return d._children ? "lightsteelblue" : "#fff";
    });

  nodeEnter.append("text")
    .attr("x", function(d) {
      return d.children || d._children ? -10 : 10;
    })
    .attr("dy", ".35em")
    .attr("text-anchor", function(d) {
      return d.children || d._children ? "end" : "start";
    })
    .text(function(d) {
      return d.name;
    })
    .style("fill-opacity", 1e-6);

  // Transition nodes to their new position.
  var nodeUpdate = node.transition()
    // .duration(duration)
    .attr("transform", function(d) {
      return "translate(" + d.y + "," + d.x + ")";
    });

  nodeUpdate.select("circle")
    .attr("r", function(d) {
      return d.children ? 20 : 10;
    })
    .style("fill", function(d) {
      return d._children ? "lightsteelblue" : "#fff";
    });

  nodeUpdate.select("text")
    .style("fill-opacity", 1);

  // Update the links…
  var link = svg.selectAll("path.link")
    .data(links, function(d) {
      return d.target.id;
    });

  // Enter any new links at the parent's previous position.
  link.enter().insert("path", "g")
    .attr("class", "link")

  .attr("d", function(d) {
    return line([{
      x: d.source.y,
      y: d.source.x
    }, {
      x: d.target.y,
      y: d.target.x
    }]);
  });

  // Transition links to their new position.
  link.transition()
    //.duration(900)
    .attr("d", function(d) {
      return line([{
        x: d.source.y,
        y: d.source.x
      }, {
        x: d.target.y,
        y: d.target.x
      }]);
    });

  // Transition exiting nodes to the parent's new position.
  link.exit().transition()
    // .duration(duration)

  .attr("d", function(d) {
      return line([{
        x: d.source.y,
        y: d.source.x
      }, {
        x: d.target.y,
        y: d.target.x
      }]);
    })
    .remove();

  // Transition exiting nodes to the parent's new position.
  var nodeExit = node.exit().transition()
    .duration(duration)
    .attr("transform", function(d) {
      return "translate(" + source.y + "," + source.x + ")";
    })
    .remove();

  nodeExit.select("circle")
    .attr("r", 1e-6);

  nodeExit.select("text")
    .style("fill-opacity", 1e-6);

  // Stash the old positions for transition.
  nodes.forEach(function(d) {
    d.x0 = d.x;
    d.y0 = d.y;
  });
}

function elbow(d, i) {
  return "M" + d.source.y + "," + d.source.x + "H" + d.target.y + "V" + d.target.x + (d.target.children ? "" : "h" + margin.right);
}

// Toggle children on click.
function click(d) {
  if (d.children) {
    d._children = d.children;
    d.children = null;
  } else {
    d.children = d._children;
    d._children = null;
  }
  update(d);
}

//redraw graph after zoom
function redraw() {
  svg.attr("transform", "translate(" + d3.event.translate + ")" + " scale(" + d3.event.scale + ")");
}
```

```css
.node {
  cursor: pointer;
}
.node circle {
  fill: #fff;
  stroke: steelblue;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}
.node text {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
}
.link {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #ccc;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.3/d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Have you made any attempts at this?  It seems like it should be relatively straight forward, but perhaps a little fiddly.  I would create a reusable object that can be instantiated with the data and an x,y position that will draw the donut chart based on the data passed in.  You can then create a bunch of these instead of circles for your node.

Comment: @Ben Lyall I made so many attempts to add donut chart to each node but it fails. My attempt was to add an svg of donut to each node in place of circle.